# Aggregate Queries oData (Simple.oData)

Tags: c#, odata, simple.odata

I am trying to issue aggregate queries to my oData server, but i get errors, dispute having the exact same code as in documentation

```
var product = await client
            .For("People")
            .Filter("FirstName ne 'Joni'")
            .Count()
            .FindScalarAsync();
```

Code in documentation

```
var x = ODataFilter.Expression;
        var count = await _client
            .For("Products")
            .Filter("ProductName+eq+%27Chai%27")
            .Count()
            .FindScalarAsync();
        Assert.Equal(1, count);
```

From:
https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/wiki/Retrieving-data-matching-search-criteria

In this same case, why are they declaring "x"? It is never used.

Also, how would i go about accessing functions like Min/Max that are defined here:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.pdf

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: .FindScalarAsync() is red. Type argument cant be inherited for usage. Try specifying the type explicitly. I did look at the API, and the method defined is "Task<U> FindScalarAsync<U>();" I tried using various data forms for <U>, but i always get bad request

Comment: Could it be related to the code in documentation using URL escaped string, your code does not?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, Aggregate queries are not supported yet

Source:
https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/76

Answer (score 0):

I developed the [AdaptiveLINQ component](http://www.adaptivelinq.com) which introduces the concept of *cube* in a LINQ query (on any LINQ provider supporting GroupBy).

This allows to perform a **server-side aggregation** simply by specifying a `$select` query.

Example:

```
SalesView?$select=CustomerName,Sales
```

assuming `SalesView` is defined by a cube with the *dimension* `CustomerName` and the *measure* `Sales`.